# onAccessibilityEvent not called in Kitkat

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat, accessibilityservice

I am building an app that listens to notifications and then display it onto a calendar using accessibilityservice , but whenever I receive a notification (I'm using emails to test as I could continually send mail to myself) the onaccessibilityservice is never called , I referred to some answers around here but they all point to JellyBean which I think is not the case I'm looking for

In my AccessibilityListener.class

```
    @Override
        public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
            final int eventType = event.getEventType();
            NotificationInfo info = new NotificationInfo();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Received event", 1000);

            Log.d("TAG","onaccessibility event running");

            if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED)
            {   
                    info.packageName = (String) event.getPackageName();
                    info.eventTime = event.getEventTime();
                    info.eventText = event.getText().toString();
                    sendEvent(info);            
            }
        }
```

In my Android.manifest

```
<service 
            android:enabled="true" 
            android:name=".AccessibilityListener"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
        </service>
```

In my accessibilityservice.xml in res/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeNotificationStateChanged"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="100" />
```

Comment: the accessibility-service doesn't work for gmail..you can try with others it will work..like facebook

Comment: @MeenalSharma how can I simulate a facebook notification in devices? Anyway to let email works too ?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/notify-me/ this will help you out..

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am stuck on the same situation and can't seem to figure it out. it works fine on 4.2 and 5.1.1 but not on 4.4.2 ... ??